# Как возвращать true/false http angular 2

Tags: http, rest, angular2, typescript

Доброе утро всем!
Подскажите как возвращать true/false в http запросе

как я делаю:

```
  isLoggedIn() {

    const self = this;

    function updateBoolean(news) {
      self.active = news;
    }

    this.http.get('http://api.site.dev/api/login', options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
        res => res,
        err => {
          if (err.status === 200) {

            this.active = true;
            updateBoolean(this.active);

            } else {

              this.active = false;
            updateBoolean(this.active);

            }
        });

        return this.active;

  }
```

буду рад вашим советам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по идее должно вот так работать

```
this.http.post('url').success(function(data)
        {
            //здесь обрабатываем успешный ответ
            //data - ответ с сервера
        }).error(function(data)
        {
            //здесь что-то делаем с ошибкой
        });
```